# How to refresh TableView data after tapping ViewCell in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have the following code that creates ViewCells for my `TableView` dynamically:

XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
   <TableView Intent="Settings">
      <TableView.Root>
         <TableSection x:Name="tableSection"></TableSection>
      </TableView.Root>
   </TableView>
</StackLayout>
```

C#:

```
categories = getCategories();
foreach (var category in categories)
{
   var viewCell = new ViewCell 
   { 
      View = new StackLayout()
      {
         Padding = new Thickness(20, 0, 20, 0),
         HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
         Children = { 
            new StackLayout() {
               Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
               VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
               Children = {
                  new StackLayout() {
                     HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                     Children = {
                        new Label { Text = category.Name}
                      },
                  new StackLayout() {
                     HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                     Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                     Children = {
                        new Label { Text = category.Count},
                        new Image { Source = "right1.png",
                                    IsVisible = category.Selected }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
       }
    };
    viewCell.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
    {
       if (category.Selected == false)
       {
          App.DB.UpdateSelected(true);
       }
       else
       {
          App.DB.UpdateSelected(false);
       }
       categories = getCategories();
       totalPhraseCount = getTotalPhraseCount();
       Title = totalPhraseCount.ToString() + " phrases";
     };
    tableSection.Add(viewCell);
}
```

What I wanted to do is whenever I tap on a view cell to update the selected property, the data in the table view are also updated. In ListView I could call the ItemSelected event and call the ItemSource again with the updated categories. Is this possible with TableView?

Comment: Why do you want to use a TableView? Answering this question is important to implementing a proper solution. If you are going to potentially have a lot of rows in the TableView, you will have to get creative with your solution. I want to help, but need some more guidance of what you are trying to achieve in the application with this TableView (like is it a settings page, or displaying dynamic rows to users etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App54"
             x:Class="App54.MainPage">

 <ContentPage.Content>
        <TableView Intent="Settings">
            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection x:Name="tableSection" Title="Section Title">
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MyViewModel vm;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new MyViewModel();

        foreach (MyDataModel dm in vm.Data)
        {
            Image img = new Image();
            img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "MyImage", BindingMode.TwoWay, null, null);
            img.BindingContext = dm;

            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "MyLabel", BindingMode.TwoWay, null, null);
            label1.BindingContext = dm;

            Label label2 = new Label();
            label2.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Selected", BindingMode.TwoWay, null, null);
            label2.BindingContext = dm;

            StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();
            sl.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
            sl.Children.Add(img);
            sl.Children.Add(label1);
            sl.Children.Add(label2);

            ViewCell vc = new ViewCell();
            vc.BindingContext = dm;
            vc.View = sl;
            vc.Tapped += Vc_Tapped;

            tableSection.Add(vc);
        }
    }

    private void Vc_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewCell vc = (ViewCell)sender;
        MyDataModel dm = (MyDataModel)vc.BindingContext;

        MyDataModel currSel = vm.Data.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Selected == true);

        if (currSel != null)
            currSel.Selected = false;

        dm.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataModel> Data { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<MyDataModel>
        {
            new MyDataModel {MyLabel = "Label 1", MyImage = "image.png", Selected = false },
            new MyDataModel {MyLabel = "Label 2", MyImage = "image.png", Selected = false },
            new MyDataModel {MyLabel = "Label 3", MyImage = "image.png", Selected = false },
            new MyDataModel {MyLabel = "Label 4", MyImage = "image.png", Selected = false },
            new MyDataModel {MyLabel = "Label 5", MyImage = "image.png", Selected = false }
        };
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class MyDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private string myLabel;
    public string MyLabel
    {
        get { return myLabel; }
        set
        {
            if (value != myLabel)
            {
                myLabel = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyLabel"));
            }
        }
    }
    private string myImage;
    public string MyImage
    {
        get { return myImage; }
        set
        {
            if (value != myImage)
            {
                myImage = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyImage"));
            }
        }
    }
    private bool selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != selected)
            {
                selected = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using bindings to your viewmodel instead of manually setting up the values, the following article should help you: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/
To make the example a little easier to write i did with a listview, since what you are basically doing is creating a list.

XAML:

```
<StackLayout>

        <ListView x:Name="CategoriesList" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <ViewCell>

                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     Padding="20,0,20,0"
                                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />

                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Count" />

                                <Image IsVisible="{Binding Selected}" Source="right1.png" />

                            </StackLayout>


                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>
```

C#:
Add a call to this mathod on the constructor to your page:
Also make sure to set the binding context to your view model!

```
public PageConstructor(PageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            this.BindingContext = viewModel;
            Listeners();
        }

private void Listeners()
        {
            CategoriesList.ItemTapped += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (category.Selected == false)
                {
                    App.DB.UpdateSelected(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    App.DB.UpdateSelected(false);
                }
                categories = getCategories();
                totalPhraseCount = getTotalPhraseCount();
                Title = totalPhraseCount.ToString() + " phrases";
            };
        }
```

Your ViewModel should have a Categories property and implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

ViewModel C#:

```
class PageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        List<Category> Categories;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PageViewModel()
    {
        this.Categories = //API call to retrieve the categories
    }

    public List<Category> Categories
    {
        set
        {
            if (Categories != value)
            {
                Categories = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Categories"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return Categories;
        }
    }
}
```

For a nicer implementation of the MVVM model you can try the following solutions:

- MVVM Light
- Prism: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Lucas. I do know how to do this in ListView but I was specifically told to use TableView hence my question.

Comment: I don't mean to be annoying, but I'm not sure if TableView is the right way to go for you. If you look at the documentation it states that TableView should be used for static data, which is the reason why it does not have an ItemTemplate property. Also it was design to be used for data that is presented differently from row to row , which is also not your case. The documentation can be found at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/#Use_Cases

Answer (score -1):

Try Following

```
categories = getCategories();
foreach (var category in categories)
{
   var viewCell = new ViewCell 
   { 
      View = new StackLayout()
      {
         Padding = new Thickness(20, 0, 20, 0),
         HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
         Children = { 
            new StackLayout() {
               Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
               VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
               Children = {
                  new StackLayout() {
                     HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                     Children = {
                        new Label { Text = category.Name}
                      },
                  new StackLayout() {
                     HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                     Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                     Children = {
                        new Label { Text = category.Count},
                        new Image { Source = "right1.png",
                                    IsVisible = category.Selected }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
       }
    };
    viewCell.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
    {
       if (category.Selected == false)
       {
          App.DB.UpdateSelected(true);
       }
       else
       {
          App.DB.UpdateSelected(false);
       }
       categories = getCategories();
       totalPhraseCount = getTotalPhraseCount();
       Title = totalPhraseCount.ToString() + " phrases";
     };

}
tableSection.Add(viewCell);
tableSection.ForceLayout();
// Or try tableview.Forcelayout();
// Or try parent_stacklayout.ForceLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks @Atul. But this still does not work. My TableView is still not updating.

Comment: Can you send me small sample project so i can do it for you?

Comment: Is it possible for you?

Comment: Also try to put my last three statement out of loop.

Comment: The performance with this solution will be poor on Android phones. Calling `ForceLayout()` should always be avoided because it will invalidate the layout and cause all of your layout calculations to run again. You are also calling this in a loop which should not be done in Xamarin.Forms.